# How to get the information of "how many and which symbols are resolved by linker"?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, elf

The test is on 32-bit Linux, x86. With `gcc` 4.6.3 and GNU `ld` 2.22.

So I am trying to get the information of "how many symbols are resolved by linker" during link time? And how can I list the information of all the resolved symbols? say, the symbol name, memory address.

I am thinking I should manipulate the linker to do so, but I have no idea how to do it. I have some experiences to fed linker with a link-script, but I didn't find anything related to resolved symbol information in the link-scripts..

Could anyone give me some help? I really appreciate that! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a "linker map".

The ld(1) option is "--print-map". But calling through GCC you'll probably have to do something like:

```
gcc -Wl,--print-map -o a.out c.c
```

It comes out the standard output and looks pretty complete.